# Wordpress Date Post

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to get all the posts on a certain date, and then parse the post content. How would I grab the posts by specifying a specific date? I'm assuming I need to use the get_posts() function, but I'm not clear as to how to format that call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Return posts for today

```
$today = getdate();
$myposts=get_posts('year=' .$today["year"] .'&monthnum=' .$today["mon"] .'&day=' .$today["mday"] );
```

More examples:
[Time Parmeters for query_posts or get_posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/query_posts#Time_Parameters)